# Omniture: send virtual pageview on click

Tags: jquery, adobe-analytics

Ok, so I'm trying to send a virtual pageview upon click before continuing to the purchase process

I tested the next function over the button:

```
$('a:contains("Continuar compra")').mouseover(function() {
s.pageName="Carro de compras: Continuar";
s.tl();
});
```

and works like a charm (used debugger and console to confirm) but when changing to click function:

```
$('a:contains("Continuar compra")').click(function() {
s.pageName="Carro de compras: Continuar";
s.tl();
});
```

It does not send the pageview, any ideas?

Thanks,
Felipe

Comment: my guess is you have some other click event attached to the element that is stopping/preventing the event from bubbling to it

Comment: That's right, so I have one event on the html an I was trying to include this code through Tag Manager, any ideas how to get it right?

Comment: You can try checking the option to directly apply to the element but if that don't work then only thing you can do is change the other listener to allow the event to propagate/bubble or put your omniture code in it or otherwise make changes to it.  Point being there's not much you can indirectly do when other code stops the event prop/bubble

Answer (score 0):

`s.t` will send a pageview request, not `s.tl` (link tracking).